# R can't find fct_recode() function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am using R with Anaconda and Jupyter. Also I am using `tidyverse` library.

When I run:

```
days_label <- factor(df$days)

fct_recode(days_label,
                  'Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;' = 1,
                  'Sat;' = 2,
                  'Sun;' = 3)
```

I get an error saying that R can't find `fct_recode` function.
I have tried with `?tidyverse` and I get the full description of this function.

Is it a problem regarding R's installation, or there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: you need to load `library(forcats)`

Comment: @Dan I have tried to load `forcats`, but I get the same error.

Comment: forcats does not get loaded when you load tidyverse, you have to load it explicitly as I have shown above. install.packages(“tidyverse”) will install a bunch of packages that do not get loaded when you load tidyverse. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try `forcats::fct_recode()`

Although not sure you code work as is, see `?forcats::fct_recode()` for examples:

```
fct_recode(x, fruit = "apple", fruit = "banana")
```